# Find where code was deleted in a Git repository

Tags: git

How do I find code that was deleted?

I ended up finding where it was created with this:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline -S'some code'
```

And that's good enough, but I was also curious to find where it got deleted, and so far, no dice.

First, I tried `git diff HEAD..HEAD^ | grep 'some code'`, expanding the range each time, until I found the lines where it was removed. Nice, so suppose I found it on range `HEAD^^..HEAD^^^`, then I do `git show HEAD^^^` and `git show HEAD^^` with `grep`, but the code is nowhere to be found!

Then I read up a bit on `git bisect`, and sure enough, it gives me a single revision where the culprit is supposed to be... Again, `git show rev | grep 'some code'` comes up empty...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that when you do basically the following you get no hits?:

<pre>
 SHAHIT=\`git log --pretty=oneline -S'some code' | head -1 | awk '{  print $1 }'\`
 git show $SHAHIT | grep 'some code'
</pre>

If so, seems non-sensical....  if it's in `log`, it should be visible in `show`... right? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: It's been a while since I was in this situation and it hasn't presented itself again, so I can't test your command. Thanks anyway, it may come in handy for somebody.

Comment: Old post/comment here, but exactly what I needed nonetheless.  @SimeonFitch your syntax worked perfectly for me, to find and list the actual code line(s) in question.  One addition that I found useful was to use the '--context=n' grep option to show enough lines before/after to know what the filename is too (there are other grep options that would help with this too). So in my case the second command was: git show $SHAHIT | grep --context=30 'some code'

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but isn't the top log entry (i.e., the newest relevant change) in the `git log -S` output will be the one that actually deleted the relevant code?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Hmph, this works for me:

```sh
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/pknotz/foo/.git/

$ echo "Hello" > a

$ git add a

$ git commit -am "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 7e52a51] initial commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a

$ echo " World" >> a

$ git commit -am "Be more specific"
[master 080e9fe] Be more specific
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

$ echo "Hello" > a

$ git commit -am "Be less specific"
[master 00f3fd0] Be less specific
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

$ cat a
Hello

$ git log -SWorld
commit 00f3fd0134d0d54aafbb9d959666efc5fd492b4f
Author: Pat Notz &lt;patnotz@gmail.com&gt;
Date:   Tue Oct 6 17:20:48 2009 -0600

    Be less specific

commit 080e9fe84ff89aab9d9d51fb5d8d59e8f663ee7f
Author: Pat Notz &lt;patnotz@gmail.com&gt;
Date:   Tue Oct 6 17:20:33 2009 -0600

    Be more specific
```

Or, is this not what you mean?

Comment: That's what I mean... So if it doesn't work for me, could it be that the index is corrupted or history was rewritten?

Comment: In this example, Pat is using `git log -SWorld` which does *not* show the diffs. I'm guessing (haven't tried it) that if the last command were `git show 00f3fd0134d0d54aafbb9d959666efc5fd492b4f | grep World` then you'd get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: This can't be the accepted answer as it's not only not answering the question, but also is only a "works for me"

Answer (score 95):

`git log -S<string>` does the job, but if you need to make more complex searches you can use `git log -G<regex>`.

From the `man`:

> `-G<regex>`
>
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines
>   that match `<regex>`.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a way to find the specific commit, but it is only shown when diffing between these commits. I can't explain why Git works that way, but I'll elaborate my findings:

---

**Problem explained**

With '-S' or '-G', we can **only find where it was added**, not removed. To elaborate:

```sh
$ git log --format="%H" -S"127.0.124.1"
857aa361293abbb351d6d6becaa55ec011aebc93
$ git show 857aa361293abbb351d6d6becaa55ec011aebc93 | grep "127.0.124.1" # Remove grep to see full diff
+       return "127.0.124.1", nil
```

---

**Step by step**

I got the idea from [miku86 on dev.to](https://dev.to/miku86/git-find-specific-deleted-content-in-a-file-5h33). First we try to find the last commit our string existed:

```sh
$ git --no-pager grep "127.0.124.1" $(git rev-list --all) # | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1 # Uncomment to only show the hash of the first one
ba0b2d348f4e33857c96acf5a6231cf9d89ddb1b:some/file.go:        return "127.0.124.1"
0d19a98d6434da0b4b5cc2bac190b9b1de36d992:some/file.go:        return "127.0.124.1"
84274c5712bacbbee1dca5567cef77a2b6f356d2:some/file.go:        return "127.0.124.1"
42e692643ff8a5dce7a89e985062b3d38c60fcc0:some/file.go:        return "127.0.124.1"
```

Which results in `ba0b2d348f4e33857c96acf5a6231cf9d89ddb1b` is our searched commit. Next we try to find the commit following after this one until *HEAD*:

```sh
$ git rev-list ba0b2d348f4e33857c96acf5a6231cf9d89ddb1b.. # | tail -n1 # Uncomment to only show the last one
[...]
c82d040f7be2f8955075655843400a36ceb75303
aa0568b543db57564770d73e736aaf50fd749fb4
dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793
```

Which is `dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793`, since this is the last one in this list we're looking for.

So does that mean `dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793` should contain that removal?

```sh
$ git show dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793 | grep "127.0.124.1" # Remove grep to see the full diff
#<no output>
```

No?!? Well, what's the diff then from that to our first found commit?

```sh
$ git diff ba0b2d348f4e33857c96acf5a6231cf9d89ddb1b..dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793 | grep "127.0.124.1" # Remove grep to see the full diff
-       return "127.0.124.1"
```

Here we've found it. That's odd. But since we're using a diff between commits, did I made a mistake and there are other commits in-between?

```sh
$ git log --pretty=oneline ba0b2d348f4e33857c96acf5a6231cf9d89ddb1b..dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793
dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793 network interface
```

No, we seem to haven't made a mistake. That's odd. But yeah, that's how far I got to find the specific spot of change where the string vanished.

---

**Additionally**

I could confirm using `git bisect` that `dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793` is the commit I was looking for.

```sh
# Bisecting a while...
$ git bisect bad
dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793 is the first bad commit
commit dde61dae0cf648e7f4dd8a5c194bcf9be1745793
Author: ...
Date:   Fri Oct 18 11:04:26 2019 +0200

    network interface

:100644 100644 242e81c363c2c7069efb018821821553b98f2c97 416c27f5351a9d92a6914b34846c6de51d83dd0d M      go.mod
:040000 040000 715c3ab5b3f4579d8054618f1e11fc05fb425324 e6731408a1ac1ff0428128ccbb1fbfaad4c789ab M      network
[...]
```

Comment: Note that `git --no-pager grep "127.0.124.1" $(git rev-list --all)` only works if you have a relatively small number of commits, otherwise you you a bash error 'argument list too long'